How to get Excel to open a hyperlink to a pdf but with a #zoom parameter on the end of it?
in excel i can hyperlink the file on my local drive and put link.pdf#zoom=400,1360,500 but there are two problems:

excel will not open it in chrome since it no longer ends in a pdf extension and
excel does not pass the hyperlink, identically, on to pdf or chrome so it keeps the parameter (#zoom=400,1360,500) at the end of it.

i have tried installing the adobe chrome extension but that does not work to pass through the parameter to chrome, even after restart.
i will hyperlink a cell to link.pdf#zoom but when it opens to either acrobat or chrome, it removes the #zoom parameter.
is there some way to, in the hyperlink field of excel, make the program open the link as is?
installing adobe extension on chrome - didnt work
set chrome as default for excel - didnt work

where do you put --app="in.pdf#page=3?

Try using this sub. it will open chrome with any url.
Base on sub from https://www.devhut.net/vba-exploring-microsoft-edge/
   Public Sub OpenURL(ByVal sURL As String)
     Dim sCmd                  As String
       sCmd = "start chrome " & sURL
     Shell "cmd /c """ & sCmd & """", vbHide
   End Sub


man i have no idea where to even put that code........

Oops....  sorry I didn't realize that you don't know VBA.So in that case I cannot help you.

Press Alt-F11 in Excel, and 'paste' the code . You might need to Enable Macro .

Are you able to edit the PDF file itself? If so, you can run cpdf -open-at-page-custom with an appropriate specification, as described in Section 11.4.3 of the cpdf manual: https://coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf.
I'm not sure exactly how your syntax 400,1360,500 translates - where is the spec for that? But it can be done - maybe with -open-at-page-custom, or even with one of the simpler commands also described in that chapter.

Thanks! Ideally, of course, it should not be encoded into the PDF. But the poster describes a situation where they cannot get it to work in the browser, and seem to be loading PDFs they control from disk. So it may suffice.

Office applications i.e. Word/Excel etc. will allow internal object linking to a filename.ext either remote or local.
Those external links may include # (fragment symbol) with additional parameters.
However calling "local files" will pass though windows command shell, and there they cannot directly use the fragments after the extension.
The best you can expect is "File not found" since it is not part of the filename.

Solutions
Either the link is to an external shortcut.lnk (wastes 4 KB  of disk space per lnk, and is limited to single fixed function) or you use a "macro" to apply a selected action.
That macro can be using fixed or variable parameters. The simplest example would be
Sub LaunchProgram()
' test Macro
   Shell "cmd /r echo Hello-World&pause", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

To access the Macro editor use hotkeys Alt+F11 paste the above code and click the green run icon.

It is a steep learning curve to decide what to add in VBA for variable especially LFN (Long File Names) due to Windows issues with spaces in VBA/VBS command lines!
In this case one approach is we name as a Hotkey for example CTRL+SHIFT+W so we first paste:
Sub W()
 Dim sCmd As String
 sCmd = """%programfiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"" --pdf-upsell-disabled --enable-features=msEdgeEpubReaderEnabled file://"
    Shell "cmd /c """ & sCmd & Selection & """"
End Sub

Then close VBA editor to set the hotkey using Alt+F8 to call the list and apply the Hotkey options by press SHIFT & W.

Now when we select that cell with a filename and fragment and press CTRL+Shift+W it will zoom to that location. There are other whistles and bells, like how to run at a click but those are other questions you can search for in VBA tutorials.

